# Jackson Serializer Register SimpleModule with Generics

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson, addition

I have this class

```
public class ResultList<T> {......}
```

and my `JsonSerializer` class

```
public class ListProductSerializer extends JsonSerializer<ResultList<Product>> {..}
```

How do register the SimpleModule in the `ObjectMapper`

this not work

```
MAPPER.registerModule(new SimpleModule()
                .addSerializer(ResultList.class, new ListProductSerializer()));
```

i get this error

```
Error:(67, 17) java: method addSerializer in class com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.module.SimpleModule cannot be applied to given types;
  required: java.lang.Class<? extends T>,com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonSerializer<T>
  found: java.lang.Class<com.onkalo.rest.json.wrapper.ResultList>,com.onkalo.rest.json.serializer.ListProductSerializer
  reason: cannot infer type-variable(s) T
    (argument mismatch; java.lang.Class<com.onkalo.rest.json.wrapper.ResultList> cannot be converted to java.lang.Class<? extends com.onkalo.rest.json.wrapper.ResultList<com.onkalo.service.domain.Product>>)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A way to resolve this is to use [StdSerializer](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.8/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ser/std/StdSerializer.html) instead of its base class `JsonSerializer`, with the same `serialize` method you currently use and a constructor taking a [JavaType](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.8/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/JavaType.html) e.g:

```
class ListProductSerializer extends StdSerializer<ResultList<Product>> {
    ListProductSerializer(JavaType type) {
        super(type);
    }

    @Override
    public void serialize( // your serialize method
}
```

This would be an appropriate `JavaType` in your case:

```
CollectionLikeType type = MAPPER.getTypeFactory()
        .constructCollectionLikeType(ResultList.class, Product.class);
```

Note how class types for both `ResultList` and `Product` are passed as separate arguments to `constructCollectionLikeType`. Also note that [CollectionLikeType](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.8/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/type/CollectionLikeType.html) doesn't require that `ResultList` implements `Collection`.

And finally register the `SimpleModule`:

```
mapper.registerModule(new SimpleModule()
        .addSerializer(new ListProductSerializer(type)));
```