# How do you restrict custom ObjectMapper serializer to specific generic type

Tags: java, generics, serialization, jackson

I would like to use a custom serializer for Maps, but only if they are <String, String> maps. I attempted to register a `StdSerializer<Map,String, String>>` following the advice in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45281738/jackson-serializer-register-simplemodule-with-generics) like so:

```
    ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper();
    SimpleModule maskModule = new SimpleModule();
    JavaType mapType =
        om.getTypeFactory().constructMapLikeType(Map.class, String.class, String.class);
    maskModule.addSerializer(new MapSerializer(mapType));
    om.registerModule(maskModule);
```

My Serializer looks as follows:

```
  public static class MapSerializer extends StdSerializer<Map<String, String>> {

    MapSerializer(JavaType type) {
      super(type);
    }

    @Override
    public void serialize(
        Map<String, String> value, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider serializers)
        throws IOException {
      gen.writeStartObject();
      for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : value.entrySet()) {
          gen.writeStringField(entry.getKey(), doOtherStuff(entry.getValue()));
      }
      gen.writeEndObject();
    }
  }
```

This works fine on `Map<String, String>` objects, but unfortunately it also gets called for other maps as well. How does one restrict a custom serializer to specific generic types?

Comment: I doubt you can, considering they're mapped by `Class`. You'll probably need to inspect the type in the serializer and [delegate to the default](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-call-default-serializer-from-custom-serializer) if it's not supported.

Comment: It'll still be tricky getting the parameterized type at runtime. If it's stored in a field, you might be able to get it via `ContextualSerializer`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the comment by @shmosel, I've identified that the following solution appears to allow us to intercept the serializer assignment by using a `SerializerModifier`.

```
  public static class MapSerializerModifier extends BeanSerializerModifier {
    @Override
    public JsonSerializer<?> modifyMapSerializer(SerializationConfig config, MapType valueType, BeanDescription beanDesc, JsonSerializer serializer) {
        if(valueType.getKeyType().getRawClass().equals(String.class) &&
                valueType.getContentType().getRawClass().equals(String.class)) {
          return new MapSerializer();
        }
      return serializer;
    }
  }
```

Then instead of registering the `MapSerializer` directly in the module, you register the modifier instead:

```
    SimpleModule maskModule = new SimpleModule();
    maskModule.setSerializerModifier(new MapSerializerModifier());
    om.registerModule(maskModule);
```

Now the modifier gets checked for each Map and either returns the custom serializer or the default serializer depending on the object's type properties.